# Unable to implement ClickListener within android list view

Tags: android, listview

Hello i am working on a android project where i am using list view to list default entities . my android code is like this i am able to get a list of item's using falowing code but i am unable to implement onclicklisaner .if a list item is clicked than i want a message box to comeup and i am unable to do it

```js
package com.example.policadda;

public class Help {

 private String title;
 private String address;
 private int iconID;
 private String phonenumber;
 private int callbutton;
 
 public Help(String title, String address, int iconID ,String phonenumber) {
  super();
  this.title = title;
  this.address = address;
  this.iconID = iconID;
  this.phonenumber= phonenumber;
  
 }
 public String getTitle() {
  return title;
 }
 public String getAddress() {
  return address;
 }
 public int getIconID() {
  return iconID;
 }
 public String getphonenumber() {
  return phonenumber;
 }

}
```

```html
package com.example.policadda;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainHelp extends Activity  {
 EditText inputSearch;
 TextView txtphonenumber;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
private List<Help> myhelp = new ArrayList<Help>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.help);
 inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
 populateComplaintList();
 ArrayAdapter<Help> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
 ListView List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.helplistview);
 List.setAdapter(adapter);
      

}





private void populateComplaintList() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 myhelp.add(new Help("kalasipalya","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.administration1,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("kormangala","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.businessman157,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("raghuvanahali","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.businessman158,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("konankunte","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.administration1,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("thatguni","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.administration1,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("mayurilayout","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.administration1,"7760576191"));
 myhelp.add(new Help("chunchghatta","#12 subramanyapura mainroad",R.drawable.administration1,"7760576191"));
 
}


private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Help>{
 public MyListAdapter(){
  super(MainHelp.this , R.layout.helpdesing , myhelp);
  
 }

 
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View itemView = convertView;
  
 

  if(itemView== null){
   itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.helpdesing, parent,false);
  }
  
   Help currenthelp = myhelp.get(position);
   ImageView imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
   imageview.setImageResource(currenthelp.getIconID());
   
   TextView maketext = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_textTitle);
   maketext.setText(currenthelp.getTitle());
   
   TextView makeaddress= (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);
   makeaddress.setText(currenthelp.getAddress());
   
   TextView makephonenumber =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtphonenumber);
   makephonenumber.setText(currenthelp.getphonenumber());
  
  return itemView;
 }
 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ;
create click listener after the getview method within your adapter class,

```
    public OnItemClickListener onItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long arg3) {
         Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
    }
};
```

and set the listener as follows,

```
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(adapter.onItemClick);
```

Comment: i altered the code as mentioned but i am getting a error saying "onitemclick cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 0):

Class Transition3d  in ApiDemos in Android SDK has show how to create item click listener and use it in Listview widget. Take a look at the line "mPhotosList.setOnItemClickListener(this);"

```
package com.example.android.apis.animation;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;

/**
 * This sample application shows how to use layout animation and various
 * transformations on views. The result is a 3D transition between a
 * ListView and an ImageView. When the user clicks the list, it flips to
 * show the picture. When the user clicks the picture, it flips to show the
 * list. The animation is made of two smaller animations: the first half
 * rotates the list by 90 degrees on the Y axis and the second half rotates
 * the picture by 90 degrees on the Y axis. When the first half finishes, the
 * list is made invisible and the picture is set visible.
 */
public class Transition3d extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private ListView mPhotosList;
    private ViewGroup mContainer;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    // Names of the photos we show in the list
    private static final String[] PHOTOS_NAMES = new String[] {
            "Lyon",
            "Livermore",
            "Tahoe Pier",
            "Lake Tahoe",
            "Grand Canyon",
            "Bodie"
    };

    // Resource identifiers for the photos we want to display
    private static final int[] PHOTOS_RESOURCES = new int[] {
            R.drawable.photo1,
            R.drawable.photo2,
            R.drawable.photo3,
            R.drawable.photo4,
            R.drawable.photo5,
            R.drawable.photo6
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.animations_main_screen);

        mPhotosList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);

        // Prepare the ListView
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PHOTOS_NAMES);

        mPhotosList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mPhotosList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Prepare the ImageView
        mImageView.setClickable(true);
        mImageView.setFocusable(true);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Since we are caching large views, we want to keep their cache
        // between each animation
        mContainer.setPersistentDrawingCache(ViewGroup.PERSISTENT_ANIMATION_CACHE);
    }

    /**
     * Setup a new 3D rotation on the container view.
     *
     * @param position the item that was clicked to show a picture, or -1 to show the list
     * @param start the start angle at which the rotation must begin
     * @param end the end angle of the rotation
     */
    private void applyRotation(int position, float start, float end) {
        // Find the center of the container
        final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        // Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
        // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
        final Rotate3dAnimation rotation =
                new Rotate3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, true);
        rotation.setDuration(500);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(position));

        mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Pre-load the image then start the animation
        mImageView.setImageResource(PHOTOS_RESOURCES[position]);
        applyRotation(position, 0, 90);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        applyRotation(-1, 180, 90);
    }

    /**
     * This class listens for the end of the first half of the animation.
     * It then posts a new action that effectively swaps the views when the container
     * is rotated 90 degrees and thus invisible.
     */
    private final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        private final int mPosition;

        private DisplayNextView(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mContainer.post(new SwapViews(mPosition));
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class is responsible for swapping the views and start the second
     * half of the animation.
     */
    private final class SwapViews implements Runnable {
        private final int mPosition;

        public SwapViews(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        public void run() {
            final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            Rotate3dAnimation rotation;

            if (mPosition > -1) {
                mPhotosList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageView.requestFocus();

                rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(90, 180, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, false);
            } else {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mPhotosList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPhotosList.requestFocus();

                rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(90, 0, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, false);
            }

            rotation.setDuration(500);
            rotation.setFillAfter(true);
            rotation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy below code in OnCreate Method after set adapter

```
List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).Show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: it is very big coincidence i am also stumbling through this problem and about to post question :) . and your solution was thing i was doing but it was not working.!

Comment: Oh i cant see in your where you have implement list click listner thats why suggested that answer.